# get listItems using COM

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, com

I need to get the items of my SharePoint list :
I used COM to get the items. this is the code:

```
  <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ImgAccueilWebPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="BDTN.DeliceDanone.BDTN.ImageAccueilFeature.ImgAccueilWebPart.ImgAccueilWebPart" %>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jssor.slider.js"></script>




  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/SP.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/BDTN.DeliceDanone/scripts/Img-Animation-js-slider/jssor.slider.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Make sure the SharePoint script file 'sp.js' is loaded before your
        // code runs.
        //SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', retrieveListItems());

        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveListItems, "sp.js");

        var siteUrl = '/sites/test';


        function retrieveListItems() {

            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('imageAccueilLD ');
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' +
                '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
            this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(collListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

        }

        function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

            var listItemInfo = '';

            var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

            while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
                listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() +
                    '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title');

                $("#puthere").append("<div style='background-color:steelblue'>" +
                            oListItem.get_item('Title') +
                       "</div>");

            }

            alert(listItemInfo.toString());
        }

        function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }
    });


</script>


<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        //$("#puthere").append("<div style='background-color:steelblue'>" +
        //                   "bbb" +
        //              "</div>");
        //$("#puthere").append("<div style='background-color:red'>" +
        //            "ccc" +
        //       "</div>");

        var _SlideshowTransitions = [
        //Fade
        { $Duration: 1200, $Opacity: 2 }
        ];

        var options = {
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 1500,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

    });


    </script>

    <div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; width: 600px;
        height: 300px;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 300px; height: 200px;
            overflow: hidden;"  id="puthere">

            <div style="background-color:steelblue">
                     aaa
                </div>

        </div>
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">image slider</a>
    </div>
```

the error is :

> ScriptResource.axd, Line 786 Character SCRIPT5007 71: Unable to get
>   the property "isNullOrUndefined" a reference null or undefined
>
> SP.js Line 2 Character SCRIPT5022 11484:
>   Sys.InvalidOperationException: The type SP.ULSTraceLevel has already
>   been registered. It is possible that this type has been defined
>   several times or the script file that sets has already been loaded.
>   This may be due to a modification of the parameters during a partial
>   update. ScriptResource.axd, 1647 Line 38 Character

Any ideas .
Best regards

Comment: Not able to understand the error, but can you confirm that list title is correct. There is an extra space at the end of list title  here `var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('imageAccueilLD ');`

Comment: i eleminate the :
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../_layouts/15/SP.js"></script> and the extra space and it works